# Calling PrintCounters() is not executing, why?

Tags: c#, formatting

I am trying to print `mycounters[0]` by using the `PrintCounters()` method, but it seems that `PrintCounters(mycounters[0])` is not working, is it a syntax problem?

```
using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Counter
 {
class MainClass
{
    List<Counter> counters = new List<Counter>();
    public static void PrintCounters (IEnumerable<Counter> counters)
    {
        foreach (Counter c in counters)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is {1}", c.Name,c.Count);

        }
    }
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        List<Counter> mycounters = new List<Counter> ();
        mycounters.Add(new Counter ("counter1"));
        mycounters.Add (new Counter ("counter2"));
        mycounters [2] = mycounters [0];

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

            mycounters[0].increment ();

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            mycounters[1].increment ();

        }

        PrintCounters (mycounters);
        mycounters [2].reset();
        PrintCounters (mycounters);
    }

}
```

since I have fixed everything, while I am debugging the program, there is noting shows up[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqqST.png)

and this is my class file, there is no error.

```
namespace Counter
{
public class Counter
{
    private int _count;
    public int Count
    {
        get{
            return _count;

        }


    }
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get {
            return _name;
        }

        set{
            _name = value;
        }

    }

    public Counter (string name )
    {
        _name = name;
        _count = 0;

    }

    public void increment()
    {
        _count++;
    }

    public void  reset()
    {
        _count = 0;
    }




}
```

}

Comment: Your `PrintCounters` method requires an array of `Counter`, you are trying to call it with a single instance of Counter (myCounter[0] == first element of your `mycounters` list): what do you want to print? the whole list or just the first element?

Answer (score 2):

It is expected that will not work, since the only argument that `PrintCounters` expects is an array of Counter objects, `Counter[]`. You could just change the type of the argument to `IEnumerable<Counter>`. Doing so, it will work.

Another way to solve your problem, it would be to create an array based on the List you have by calling the `ToArray` method and then pass this as an argument to the `PrintCounters`.

```
PrintCounters(mycounters.ToArray());
```

However, I would prefer the first approach since it is more generic. Generally, it's a good practice to programming in an interface rather than in an implementation. Think about the `PrintCounters` what actually does. It just wants to iterate through the items of a collection of `Counter` objects and just print for each item it's `Name` and `Count`. Is it matters at all if this is an array or a list or whatever? The only thing that we want is an enumerator, in order to iterate thought the items. So what's the prerequisite for this? The only prerequisite is the type that will pass in the `PrintCounters` would implement the `IEnumerable<Counter>`. If one time we pass a `List<Counter>` and then change our mind and we want to pass an `Counter[]`, we will not have to change anything in the `PrintCounters` method, because we followed this principle !

Comment: Im new to programming, so sorry about the following question. how could i change the type of argument, is this should be changed in the printcounters or I need to fix it in my class?

Comment: You don't have to ask sorry...This should be changed in the method's signature, `public static void PrintCounters (IEnumerable<Counter> counters)`.

Comment: I just followed what u said to change the type but there is still an error happend on 'printcounter(mycounter[0]); ' the best overloaded method match for "Counter.mainclass.PrintCounters(system.collection.generic   IEnumerable<Counter.Counter>)"has some invaild arguments.

Comment: @YunxiangLi You have to call your method as `PrintCounters(mycounters)`. Sorry if this wasn't clear in my answer.

Comment: thanks for help, really apperecated. I just edit the question, I have fixed everything in the code, but there is nothing shows up on the screen, do you know whats the reason?...

Comment: You are welcome. Your code has a few problems. First of all this `mycounters [2] = mycounters [0];` is not correct. You have to removed it. You have declared and you have added to this list two items. You can access them via an index as `mycounters[0]` and 'mycounters[1]' (zero based indexing). That being said, if you ran your program as it is you will get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` in the line that I mentioned you have to remove. Then if you want to reset the first counter, you have to replace this line  `mycounters[2].reset();` with this `mycounters[0].reset();`.

Comment: the reason of I did that is the task ask us to make mycounter[2], and assign it has the same value regarding mycounter[0]. Is there anyway to make it?

Answer (score 0):

If You were passing parameter in the function using indexing i.e 
`mycounters [0]` then Function definition need to modify like this

```cs
  public static void PrintCounters(Counter counter)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("{0} is {1}", counter.Name, counter.Address);
  }
```

Or If You want to pass whole `mycounters` list as parameter then

```cs
  public static void Main (string[] args)
  {
    List<Counter> mycounters = new List<Counter> ();
    mycounters.Add(new Counter ("counter1"));
    mycounters.Add (new Counter ("counter2"));
    mycounters [2] = mycounters [0];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        mycounters[0].increment ();

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        mycounters[1].increment ();

    }

    PrintCounters (mycounters);
  }
```

```cs
  public static void PrintCounters(IEnumerable<Counter> counters)
    {
        foreach (Counter c in counters)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is {1}", c.Name, c.Address);

        }
    }
```